# List fragment and Navigation drawer not working togheter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem. I made a list fragment which shows my data as I intended and when i click on an item it takes me to an activity which shows their content. Now I made a Navigation drawer with two items that are supposed to take me to their assigned activity. Instead the drawer, which is supposed to show two items, is blank and my items in my list take me to the activity that were assigned to my drawer list..

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="utility.AirplaneListFragment"
             />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's my ListFragment

```
package utility;

import android.app.DialogFragment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.windows.vliegtuigspotted.R;
import com.example.windows.vliegtuigspotted.activity.AirplaneContentActivity;
import com.example.windows.vliegtuigspotted.activity.EditAirplaneActivity;

import adapter.CustomCursorAdapter;
import database.DataSource;


/**
 * Created by hort on 27-2-2016.
 */

public class AirplaneListFragment extends ListFragment implements ConfirmDeleteDialog.ConfirmDeleteDialogListener{
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
    private long itemId;
    CustomCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    DataSource datasource;

    final int Edit = 0;
    final int Delete = 1;


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        datasource = new DataSource(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        cursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), datasource.getAllAirplanesCursor(), 0);
        setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);

        mDualPane = detailsFrame != null
                && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (mDualPane) {

            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

            showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
        } else {

            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onSaveInstanceState",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetails(position);
    }

    void showDetails(int index) {
        mCurCheckPosition = index;


        if (mDualPane) {

            getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

            AirplaneContentFragment details = (AirplaneContentFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
            if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {


                details = AirplaneContentFragment.newInstance(index);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "showDetails dual-pane: create and relplace fragment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.commit();
            }

        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(getActivity(), AirplaneContentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", cursorAdapter.getItemId(index));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK)  {
                cursorAdapter.changeCursor(datasource.getAllAirplanesCursor());
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                cursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), datasource.getAllAirplanesCursor(), 0);
                setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.add(0, Edit, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, Delete, 0, "Delete");
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo itemInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        itemId = cursorAdapter.getItemId(itemInfo.position);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case Edit:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this.getActivity(), EditAirplaneActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                break;
            case Delete:
                DialogFragment dialog = new ConfirmDeleteDialog();
                dialog.show(this.getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "ConfirmDeleteDialog");

        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

        datasource.deleteAirplane(itemId);
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor(datasource.getAllAirplanesCursor());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        //Do nothing, Dialog will disappear
    }

}
```

And here's my MainActivity

```
package utility;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.windows.vliegtuigspotted.R;
import com.example.windows.vliegtuigspotted.activity.AddAirplaneActivity;
import com.example.windows.vliegtuigspotted.activity.AirplaneEventPlannerActivity;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import adapter.CustomCursorAdapter;
import adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import database.DataSource;
import model.DrawerItem;


// Demonstration of using fragments to implement different activity layouts.
// This sample provides a different layout (and activity flow) when run in
// landscape.

public class FragmentLayout extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    DataSource datasource;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] mDrawerListItems;

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    static class ViewHolder{
        private ListView mDrawerList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        datasource = new DataSource(this);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        holder.mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);

        DrawerItem drawerItems[] = new DrawerItem[]
                {
                        new DrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp, "Home"),
                        new DrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_event_note_black_24dp, "Events")

                };

        NavDrawerListAdapter adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItems);

        holder.mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        holder.mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent activityHome = new Intent(FragmentLayout.this, FragmentLayout.class);
                        startActivity(activityHome);

                    case 1:
                        Intent activityCalendar = new Intent(FragmentLayout.this, AirplaneEventPlannerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(activityCalendar);
                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(holder.mDrawerList);
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.lightBlue));
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivityForResult(new Intent(FragmentLayout.this, AddAirplaneActivity.class), 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home: {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(holder.mDrawerList)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(holder.mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(holder.mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
            }
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Im pretty new to android and its the first time i'm working with fragments, I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong at the moment.